# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'ctr' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

**I am getting error like**

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'ctr' in 'having clause': SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, artists.id AS artists_id FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `photos` ON `photos`.`photoable_id` = `artists`.`id` AND `photos`.`photoable_type` = 'Artist' WHERE (admin_approved = 1) GROUP BY artists.id HAVING ctr >= 2
```

**My artist model** I write scope

```
scope :approved, where("admin_approved = ?", true)
scope :completed_profile, joins(:photos).select("artists.*,count(photos.id) as ctr").group("artists.id").having("ctr >= 2")
```

**In my controller I write**

```
  def artists_completed_profile
     @artists = Artist.approved.completed_profile.page(params[:page]).per(10)
     @total_artists = @artists.size
  end
```

**Note:**  When I try in my console then I am not getting any error but when I write in model or controller then I am getting this error.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What mode is your server running in?

Comment: Run your migrations again. If that fails restart your web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something in your pagination is doing a `.count`, most likely when it tries to figure out the total number of matches and thus the total number of pages. That `.count` will ignore the `.select` part of your scope, that's why you're seeing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, artists.id AS artists_id ...
```

being sent to MySQL. Your `ctr` alias is defined by your `.select` so the `.count`'s SQL fails. You should be able to get around this problem by not using `ctr` in your HAVING, just use the raw `count(photos.id)`:

```
scope :completed_profile, ...having("count(photos.id) >= 2")
```